# (Proof verification) $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$ both in measure with $\mu(X) < \infty$. Proving $f_n g_n \to fg$ in measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I am aware there are other proofs to this problem on this website but I was hoping to have my proof checked.

Finiteness of the measure implies that we can choose $M$ large enough such that we can control measure ie for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose $M$ large enough $\mu (\{x \in x : |f(x)| > M \}) < \epsilon.$ Similar holds if we replace $g$ for $f$.

We know: $|f_n g_n - fg| = |f_n g_n - f_n g + f_n g - fg| \leq |f_n||g_n - g| + |g||f_n - f|$

Also note that $|f_n| \leq |f| + |f_n -f|$.

With these details in mind:

$\{x \in X : |f_n g_n - fg| > \epsilon \} \subset \{x \in X : |f_n||g_n - g| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \} \cup \{x \in X : |g||f_n - f| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\}$

Now, $\{x \in X : |f_n||g_n - g| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \} \subset \{x \in X : |f_n| > M \} \cup \{x \in X : |g_n - g| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M} \}$

Using what was noted in the set-up $\{x \in X : |f_n| > M \} \cup \{x \in X : |g_n - g| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M} \}\subset \{x \in X : |f| > \dfrac{M}{2} \} \cup \{x \in X : |f_n - f| > \dfrac{M}{2} \} \cup \{x \in X : |g_n - g| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M} \}$

Similarly, $\{x \in X : |g||f_n - f| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \} \subset \{x \in X : |g| > M \} \cup \{x \in X : |f_n - f| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M} \}$

For simplicity, let us name the sets:

$$A:= \{x \in X : |f| > \dfrac{M}{2} \} $$
$$B:= \{x \in X : |f_n - f| > \dfrac{M}{2} \}$$
$$C:= \{x \in X : |g_n - g| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M} \}$$
$$D:= \{x \in X : |g| > M \}$$
$$E:= \{x \in X : |f_n - f| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M} \}$$

Thus, $$\mu ( \{x \in X : |f_n g_n - fg| > \epsilon \} ) \leq \mu (A) + \mu (B) + \mu (C)+ \mu (D) + \mu (E)$$

The finiteness of measure and the fact that $f$ and $g$ are real valued allows us to choose $M$ large enough such that $\mu(A) \leq \epsilon$ and $\mu(D) \leq \epsilon$.

With this $M$ fixed, using the fact that $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge in measure, we can choose $n$ large enough such that $\mu(B) \leq \epsilon_1$, $\mu(C) \leq \epsilon_2$ and $\mu(E) \leq \epsilon_3$ , where $\epsilon_i$ can be chosen arbitrarily small.

Thus: $$\mu ( \{x \in X : |f_n g_n - fg| > \epsilon \} ) \leq 2\epsilon + \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_3 = \epsilon^{*}$$

Thus $f_n g_n \to fg$ in measure.

Comment: Looks correct, good job! Except I think you mean $\mu(D) \le \epsilon$ instead of $\mu(B) \le \epsilon$ in line -6. Also, a minor comment would be just to take each $\epsilon_i = \epsilon$. The $\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon^*$ are just unnecessary and make the proof a bit more annoying to read.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks for the response. I've amended that now. So you mean something like choose $M$ and $n$ large enough such that each of these sets is bounded by $\dfrac{\epsilon}{5}$, or any collection of fractions adding up to $\epsilon$, right?

Comment: Personally, I just always do $\epsilon$ and if it ends up adding to $5\epsilon$ it's no big deal.