# For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose $M$ large enough $\mu (\{x \in x : |f(x)| > M \}) < \epsilon.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

$f_n \to f$ in measure with $\mu(X) < \infty$. How do we prove that we can choose $M$ large enough such that we can control measure i.e., for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose $M$ large enough $\mu (\{x \in X \mid|f(x)| > M \}) < \epsilon.$

I need this to prove the limit of the product of sequences is a product of limit of sequences in convergence in measure theory. I got the rest of the proof but I am stuck here. I am thinking to use Egoroff's theorem but that will give me uniform convergence. Is there any simple argument that I am missing?

Comment: This is true for any real valued measurable function $f$. It has nothing to do with convergence of $f_n$ to f$.

Comment: Sir, Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\{x: f(x)=\pm \infty\}$  has measure $0$ note that the set $\{x: |f(x)| >n\}$ decreases to  $\{x: f(x)=\pm \infty\}$. Hence $\mu \{x: |f(x)|>n\} \to 0$ and we can choose $n$ large so that $\mu \{x: |f(x)|>n\}  <\epsilon$.

Since convergence in measure involves the differences $f_n(x)-f(x)$ is is usually assumed that $f$ is finite valued almost surely.

Comment: But in the proof of $f_ng_n \to fg$, we use that $f,g$ are bounded. Sir, please see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473024/proof-verification-f-n-to-f-and-g-n-to-g-both-in-measure-with-mux. I proved it in my way but I also got stuck into the condition on what will happen if $f$ or $g$ is infinite on a positive measure. The result $f_ng_n \to fg$ holds true irrespective to $f$ or $g$ is unbounded.

Comment: I also saw this https://cs.du.edu/~rpavlov/4280(Au17)/4280HW5solns(Au17).pdf. 38 b). Can you please explain me in details? This would be of much help.

Comment: @Ri-Li Convergence in measure is defined for finite valued functions. $f_n(x)-f(x)$ may  take the form $\infty -\infty$ if you allow infinite values.

Comment: Yes that is true but I was thinking that even if it happens that $f_n$ is infinite infinitely many terms, can we bind $|f_n-f|(x)$ somehow? If not, can you think of a counterexample where it doesn't work?

Comment: @Ri-Li Can you state  the definition of $f_n \to f$ in measure without the  finiteness assumption?

Comment: Hello sir, yes you are right. Sorry I slept because it was midnight here. We have to take $f,f_n:X \to \Bbb R$ to define convergence in measure.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$\int_X \vert f \vert \ge \int_{\{x \in X \mid|f(x)| > M \}}\vert f \vert \ge M \mu(\{x \in X \mid|f(x)| > M \} )$$

So $$\mu(\{x \in X \mid|f(x)| > M \}$$ goes to zero as $M \to \infty$ if $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Why is $f$ integrable? In the comment of the question, I saw that the function has to be just measurable.

Comment: Because the result may be wrong if $\mu(\{x: f(x)=\pm \infty\}) >0$.

Comment: But integrability is a much stronger condition than what is necessary.

Comment: But in the proof of $f_ng_n \to fg$, we use that $f,g$ are bounded. Sir, please see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473024/proof-verification-f-n-to-f-and-g-n-to-g-both-in-measure-with-mux. I proved it in my way but I also got stuck into the condition on what will happen if $f$ or $g$ is infinite on a positive measure. The result $f_ng_n \to fg$ holds true irrespective to $f$ or $g$ is unbounded.

Comment: I also saw this https://cs.du.edu/~rpavlov/4280(Au17)/4280HW5solns(Au17).pdf. 38 b) .Can you please explain me in details? This would be of much help.